# DistributedCache Expiry time based on server location

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, caching

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 Application.  In my Startup.cs in configure service I have added the following line:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

I am using a Distributed Memory Cache for some lightweight caching.  However I do have a question on the Cache Expiry - this is the code I have for setting "Foo" in this case in the cache for 5 mins:

```
_cache.SetString(cacheKey, "Foo", new DistributedCacheEntryOptions() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5) });
```

My question is on the AbsoluteExpiration I am using:

If I have 2 servers in London for example will the Data be held in cache for 5 mins

If I have two servers in Chicago will the data be held in cache for 5 hours 5 mins

If I have a server in London and Chicago will it be 5 mins in one and 5 hours and 5 in the other

*Note - I am assuming the first two requests hit both servers in web farm for simplicity and thus set the cache data in both servers

Should I just be using `DateTimeOffset.Now` rather than `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras - can you give an explanation as to why?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DateTimeOffset.Now` or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` both will work, basically non UTC time will be converted to UTC as `DateTimeOffset` contains UTC Offset.

So it does not matter, Microsoft made it very easy. As it is easy to convert any DateTimeOffet to UTC.

Earlier Users were setting DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.UtcNow and it did create confusion, DateTime.UtcNow was the correct way to do it.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Caching/src/System/Runtime/Caching/MemoryCacheEntry.cs#L131

Answer (score 1):

Ending up rewriting and using the below:

```
                var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));

                _cache.SetString(cacheKey, "Foo", options);
```